# AWS Amplify - Process S3 Upload with lambda and use cognito user id instead of federated user id for saving result

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify to host my Front- & Backend. I am building a simple application that lets the user sign-in through amplify (aws cognito) and upload a private file to S3 from their web browser using amplifys SDK. The S3 upload triggers a lambda function (setup through the amplify CLI) which is supposed to do some processing on that file and save the result to a database.

Now I obviously only want the user to see their results and therefore want to reference their cognito user id (sub) inside the db.

The key to the file inside S3 looks like this (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js/#customize-object-key-path):
`your-s3-bucket/myPrivatePrefix/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/<file>`

The `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` is the federated user id and not the cognito user id.

First of all, does this solution actually make sense?

I've been trying to find an api call to get the cognito user id from the federated id on the server side but there doesn't seem to be any api call that does that.

Another thing to do would be to change the S3 path to include the cognito user id instead of the federated id but there isn't any documentation on that.

One solution is to either let the user put their cognito id inside the bucket as .txt for example but this seems insecure as they could put anything in there. Or another solution is to have a database mapping from federated user id to cognito user id but this seems like "a lot" of effort for such a "simple" usecase and I am also not 100% sure how to validate that mapping when the user performs a request to create it.

Does anyone have any suggestions or improvements? I would like to go with either the first or second solution but I couldn't find much on that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a DB table to map federated id to the user.
I've read people do this in one of the cognito hooks when a user is first created, but I'm not sure which one or which API gets you the values you need.

You can get that ID in the front-end easily enough:

```js
    const { id: userIdentityId } = await Auth.currentUserInfo()
```

Your Lambda will get the full path to the file from the S3 trigger, so you don't need that in your example. You could stick the user-id into the metadata associated with the S3 object.

If you do this:

```js
   Storage.put('example.txt', 'example', { metadata: { foo: 'bar' } });
```

You can pull out the metadata key `x-amz-meta-foo = bar` elsewhere to easily have that user-id.